# Add new column in table already have 2000 record and calculate in newly created column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a table name vehicle with already have near around 2000 record now I want to add a new column `Var_Meter`. I have done this job from SQL Server now I want to add data in newly added column In_meter-Out_meter=Var_meter. Please help I am new in MVS and I am doing this on ASP.Net C#.

I was done this kind of work in Visual Foxpro code just look like

select table

- Go top
- Do While !Eof()
  replace Var_Meter with In_meter-Out_meter -
  skip-
  EndDo

Please help how can i do this in MVS ASP.net C#.

Regards, Abdul Waheed

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do it in code with a loop. You need to run this sql:

```
update vehicle set var_meter = in_meter - out_meter
```

It will update var_meter on every row with the result of in_meter - out_meter from the same row.